# phpunit testing with ajax and zend framework

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework, phpunit

i have a problem with writing tests for my action that gets called by jquery via ajax. i don't know how to catch the data that is being sent back to the view, by the action, so that i could assert if it's correct. my $.ajax(...) script inserts result, echo-ed by the controller, into a textarea element, but in my test script, result is null. failure message:

```
Failed asserting that null matches expected '...
```

here's what my test code so far:

```
$this->getRequest()->setRawBody('some json containing input params im testing');
$this->getRequest()->setMethod('GET');
$this->getRequest->setHeader('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH','XMLHttpRequest');

$this->dispatch('my url');
$result = json_decode($this->getResponse()->getBody(),true);

$expectedResult = 'some string';
$this->assertEquals($expectedResult, $result['targeted element']);
```

Comment: And what's inside the $result variable? Also consider using Zend_Json::decode()

Comment: if im not mistaken, $result should hold the values of all the fields that were set by the controller. in this case that would be textarea which should hold the string generated by the controller. there are some other text and select elements, but i don't care about them in this particular test

Comment: What SHOULD be there is irrelevant. THe question is what IS there :)

Comment: there is a null hence: Failed asserting that null matches expected '...' :)

Comment: if i put null in the $expectedResult, test passes, so my problem is catching asynchronously output data

Comment: And what's in `$this->getResponse()->getBody()`? Is it possible it's not valid JSON? :) AS you're using json_decode you won't get an exception...

Comment: $this->getResponse()->getBody() is empty

Comment: Than there is a problem in your controller :) It does not send any data :) For returning JSON I suggest using `$this->_helper->json($data);` which will encode data, disable layout and view and set propper headers.

Comment: i.e.: You're caching the data just fine. There just aren't any there :D

Comment: we're gonna reorganize a code a little bit and try and test all segments separately. thanx for your help and i'll definitely start using _helper->jason from now on

Answer (score 1):

The recommendation I write below is how I test and has proven to be much more useful and less error prone:

1. **No "controller" testing**.
2. Inject models and value objects into your **services**.
3. Inject services into your **controllers**.
4. Test **models**, **value objects**, and **services**.
5. Use a `JavaScript testing framework` to test your JS -- There are tons of good options out there that will allow you to mock your Ajax calls.

Comment: i'm still new the unit testing, so i could use a little more details :)

Comment: It really has less to do with unit testing and more to do with software design. You should probably research the following topics (google these): dependency injection, service layer, value objects, and mvvm.